# Pure Data: storing sub-sequences within sequencer and looping them?

Tags: puredata

I'm a beginner to PD with a question.

Is it possible to play, say, an 8-step sequencer, store certain sub-sequences of steps and then loop them?
Is it possible to do this in a live context, i.e. hit a bang to "record" (not through adc though), let the sequencer go through, eg, steps 1-4, hit a bang again to stop the "recording," and then hit another bang that would loop the sub-sequence I've just played? (and if it is, can someone direct me to a guide or throw me a bone as to how I could go about this?)
Thanks!!

Comment: yes, it's doable; and it requires a grasp of how to program with Pd. it's not very complicated but probably too much to explain in a [so] post.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the [Pd forum](http://forum.pdpatchrepo.info/), as there are tons of similar questions about sequencers over there, some including whole functional patches.

Comment: A good place to start learning about PureData is also the [Floss Manual](https://booki.flossmanuals.net/pure-data/).